# Exception "no such element" using an XPath expression in Selenium, even though it works in FirePath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

This is how it looks like when I inspect an element using [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29):

[image]

When I try this same syntax with an XPath expression, it selects result page 2. I tried the same approach in the [Selenium IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_IDE) and clicked on find. It selects result page 2. However, while executing the code, I am getting **No Such Element exception**

XPath syntax: `//a[contains(@href,'/jobs?q=qa+engineer&l=Renton%2C+WA&start=10')]/span[contains(@class,'pn')][text()='2']`

```java
public void jobSearch(){

    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.indeed.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("what")).sendKeys("QA Engineer");
    driver.findElement(By.id("where")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("where")).sendKeys("Seattle,WA");
    driver.findElement(By.id("fj")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/jobs?q=qa+engineer&l=Renton%2C+WA&start=10')]/span[contains(@class,'pn')][text()='2']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure your xpath matches one and only one element? Selenium tries to click on the very first element. If it's not displayed or clickable, it's normal you get an exception.

Comment: 1 matching node, is what I see when I use that syntax in firepath. Thanks

Comment: You are searching for Seattle but in the xpath you are using Renton. Modify your xpath and try to make it reusable across searches.

Comment: What is "firepath"? [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) (in the body)? [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase)? [Firestore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase#Firebase_Cloud_Firestore)?

Comment: OK, it is probably [FirePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992056/why-doesnt-firepath-work-anymore-since-firefox-51-0-1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually three mistakes:

1. The ***big*** mistake: The script is not able to find the visible option of the next page.

   In the given screenshot, the result while run given code. This is why the script is unable to find the element.

   The [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) script is only working with the *visible area*.

   [image]

   Solution:

   Add steps to scroll down the web page:

   ```java
   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 1000)", "");
   ```
2. The XPath expression is not generalized. It is for get whatever the URL is placed at `2` num page. So change is as per under:

   `//div[@class='pagination']//span[text()='2']`
3. There are some interruptions like a pop up, region-based URL. So write code like the following for eliminating the future error:

   ```java
   public void jobSearch()
   {
       try
       {
           WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.get("https://www.indeed.com");
           try
           {
               // Here the region-based URL gets open, so remove
               // it if it is directly open www.indeed.com
               driver.findElement(By.linkText("www.indeed.com")).click();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {

           }

           driver.findElement(By.id("what")).sendKeys("QA Engineer");
           driver.findElement(By.id("where")).clear();
           driver.findElement(By.id("where")).sendKeys("Seattle,WA");
           driver.findElement(By.id("fj")).click();

           try
           {
               // After this one pop up gets open so close it
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='prime-popover-close-button']/span")).click();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
           }

           //pageDown(driver.findElement(By.id("searchCount")), 2);
           JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
           jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 1000)", "");
           //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/jobs?q=qa+engineer&l=Renton%2C+WA&start=10')]/span[contains(@class,'pn')][text()='2']")).click();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pagination']//span[text()='2']")).click();
           // Now continue you code here
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

Note: Please read [GeckoDriver](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3) for Firefox and [Chromedriver](http://learn-automation.com/launch-chrome-browser-using-selenium-webdriver/) for Chrome browsers with Selenium 3.0+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following XPath expression:

```
//div[@class='pagination']/a/span[text()='2']
```

**Note:** *2* - for the *2nd page link*. Change it as per the page number you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because the element might not have been loaded at that time in the DOM, and you are using a wait statement after searching for that element.

But the wait statement must be added prior to the actions and searching for the elements.